# Can't run google app engine launcher with port 80

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

When I try to run google app engine launcher with port 80, I get this error. How can this error be fixed?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 83, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 79, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1040, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1033, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 824, in start
    self._dispatcher.start(options.api_host, apis.port, request_data)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 194, in start
    _module.start()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1176, in start
    self._balanced_module.start()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 315, in start
    self._start_all_fixed_port(host_ports)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 352, in _start_all_fixed_port
    raise BindError('Unable to bind %s:%s' % self.bind_addr)
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to bind localhost:80
```

Comment: Please check your system, you might have other service running on same port `80`. You can't start 2 service on same port.

Comment: You can run `netstats` to check which service runs on port `80`

Comment: Also many systems require root privileges to bind to ports < 1024.